# firebase upload stuck at 0.0% - no error given

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to write a function that:

1. Compresses an image on the local disk and puts it into a cache folder. (using [sharp.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=sharp+js&oq=sharp+js&aqs=chrome.0.0i512l5j69i60l3.708j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))
2. Uploads the image to a location in firebase storage.
3. Uploads the compressed thumbnail of the image to a different location in firebase storage.

The code for the function(s) that do this is below:

```js
// appends a filename to the end of a storageReference
export function addFilename(filename: string, reference: StorageReference) {
    return ref(storage, `${reference}/${path.basename(filename)}`);
}

// -- file uploading
export async function uploadFromDisk(
    filePath: string,
    destination: StorageReference,
    metadata?: UploadMetadata,
) {
    console.log("initiating upload - " + JSON.stringify(filePath));

    const taskPromise: Promise<UploadTaskSnapshot> = new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        const task = uploadBytesResumable(
            addFilename(filePath, destination),
            fs.readFileSync(filePath),
            metadata
        );
    
        task.on("state_changed", (snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.state == "running") {
                console.log(`File ${filePath} status: ${(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100).toPrecision(2)}%`);
            }

            if (snapshot.bytesTransferred >= snapshot.totalBytes ) {
                printCyan(`File ${filePath} available @ ${snapshot.ref.bucket}/${snapshot.ref.fullPath}`);
                resolve(snapshot);
            }
            
            if (snapshot.state == "error") {
                reject(new Error("There was an error uploading file " + filePath));
            }
        });

        
    }));
    
    return taskPromise;
}

export async function uploadGalleryImage(
    imagePath: string,
    site: string,
    gallery?: string,
) {
    const metadata = {
        name: path.basename(imagePath),
        contentType: path.extname(imagePath) == ".jpg" ? "image/jpeg" : "image/png"
    };

    const imageFolder = `galleries/${gallery}/full`;
    const thumbPath = (await compressImages([imagePath]))[0];
    const thumbFolder = `galleries/${gallery}/thumbs`;

    const results: UploadResult[] = [];
    const imageResult = await uploadFromDisk(
        imagePath,
        getAssetFolder(site, imageFolder),
        metadata,
    );

    const thumbResult = await uploadFromDisk(
        thumbPath,
        getAssetFolder(site, thumbFolder),
        metadata,
    );
    
    results.push(imageResult);
    results.push(thumbResult);

    return results;
}
```

For some reason, step (1) and (2) work, but in every case the function hangs on step (3). As you can see above I've added a lot of console messages and `.catch` clauses to try to diagnose the problem, but firebase doesn't even throw an error for the images it refuses to upload. They simply stay at 0.0% - sample console output is included below.

```
File images/bulksplash-charleingracia--Ux5mdMJNEA.jpg status: 77% 
// original image is uploading fine

...

File images/bulksplash-charleingracia--Ux5mdMJNEA.jpg status: 1.0e+2%
File images/bulksplash-charleingracia--Ux5mdMJNEA.jpg available ... 
// fully uploaded original image

...

File thumbs/bulksplash-charleingracia--Ux5mdMJNEA.jpg status: 0.0% 
// stuck at 0.0%
File images/bulksplash-davieees-uJDWga_IOck.jpg status: 35% 
// the other, previously initiated image uploads are chugging along just fine
File images/bulksplash-ferminrp-a1dpvJv45To.jpg status: 79%
File images/bulksplash-aliciasteels-mrB45cHDsrM.jpg status: 55%
```

If firebase could at least throw an error or change the snapshot state to "error" for these files, I could get at the problem. Because it doesn't I really don't even know where to start troubleshooting. Some ideas or where to start - or pointing out that there is an obvious error that I just happened to miss - would be appreciated.